# Show progress image of a user profile

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to show the progress of a user filling out their user profile by an image sequence.

Example, if the user fills out their name, progress image 2 will show up.
If the user fills out their name and bio, progress image 3 will appear, and so on....

I'm trying to use if and elseif statements, but only progress image 2 will appear.

So basically, I just want one image to show based on the progress the users has made on completing the user profile form.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$name = ($data->first_name);
$bio = ($data->bio);
$address = ($data->street1);
$phone = ($data->phone);
$ec = ($data->e_contact);
$ecp = ($data->e_phone);
$bs = ($data->bs);

if($name == true){?>
    <img src="../images/progress2.png" class="img-max-progress">
<?php }


elseif($name.$bio == true){?>
    <img src="../images/progress3.png" class="img-max-progress">
<?php 
} 

elseif($name.$bio.$address == true){?>
    <img src="../images/progress4.png" class="img-max-progress">
<?php 
} 

elseif($name.$bio.$address.$phone == true){?>
    <img src="../images/progress5.png" class="img-max-progress">
<?php 
}

elseif($name.$bio.$address.$phone.$ec == true){?>
    <img src="../images/progress6.png" class="img-max-progress">
<?php 
}

elseif($name.$bio.$address.$phone.$ec.$ecp == true){?>
    <img src="../images/progress7.png" class="img-max-progress">
<?php
}

elseif($name.$bio.$address.$phone.$ec.$ecp.$bs == true){?>
    <img src="../images/progress8.png" class="img-max-progress">
<?php
}
?>

<?php
if($name != true){?>
    <img src="../images/progress1.png" class="img-max-progress">
<?php 
 }
?>
```

I have the form filled out so progress8.png should be the image that is shown,
but progress2.png is currently showing.

**Using a combo between @user3132781 and @vlzvl answers, I got it working like this.**

```
<?php
$name = ($data->first_name);
$bio = ($data->bio);
$address = ($data->street1);
$phone = ($data->phone);
$ec = ($data->e_contact);
$ecp = ($data->e_phone);
$bs = ($data->bs);
$completed = 0;

if (empty($name)) {
    $completed += 1;
}
if (!empty($name)) {
    $completed += 2;
}

if (!empty($bio)) {
    $completed += 1;
} 

if (!empty($address)) {
    $completed += 1;
} 

if (!empty($phone)) {
    $completed += 1;
}
if (!empty($ec)) {
    $completed += 1;
}
if (!empty($ecp)) {
    $completed += 1;
}
if (!empty($bs)) {
    $completed += 1;
}
echo '<img src="../images/progress' . $completed .'.png" class="img-max-progress">';
?>
```

Comment: maybe try this: `if($name == true && $bio == true && $address == true && $phone == treu && $ec == true && $ecp == true && $bs == true) {}`

Comment: Instead of checking by TRUE/FALSE, you could try by checking if the string is empty or not, at least this i understand when you say _fill out their infos_. Like `if (!empty($name)){?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an other approach - just as a suggestion:

```
$completed = 0;

if (isset($name)) {
    $completed += 1;
}

if (isset($adress)) {
    $completed += 1;
}

..... and so on for all the fields

//$completed can be used for defining the image
echo '<img src="../images/progress' . $completed .'.png" class="img-max-progress">';
```

Comment: The form is submitted and stored in a users database table.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. I would try something along the lines of:

```
if($name){
   img 1
}
elseif ($name && $bio){
   img 2
}
```

etc.

The final line would be:

```
if(!$name){
   img progress1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it is also a lot cleaner):

```
<?php
$name = ($data->first_name);
$bio = ($data->bio);
$address = ($data->street1);
$phone = ($data->phone);
$ec = ($data->e_contact);
$ecp = ($data->e_phone);
$bs = ($data->bs);

if($name == true) {
    echo '<img src="../images/progress2.png" class="img-max-progress">';
}

elseif($name== true && $bio == true) {
    echo '<img src="../images/progress3.png" class="img-max-progress">';
} 

elseif($name== true && $bio == true && $address == true) {
    echo '<img src="../images/progress4.png" class="img-max-progress">';
} 

elseif($name== true && $bio == true && $address == true && $phone == true) {
    echo '<img src="../images/progress5.png" class="img-max-progress">';
}

elseif($name== true && $bio == true && $address == true && $phone == true && $ec == true) {
    echo '<img src="../images/progress6.png" class="img-max-progress">';
}

elseif($name== true && $bio == true && $address == true && $phone == true && $ec == true && $ecp == true) {
    echo '<img src="../images/progress7.png" class="img-max-progress">';
}

elseif($name== true && $bio == true && $address == true && $phone == true && $ec == true && $ecp == true && $bs == true) {
    echo '<img src="../images/progress8.png" class="img-max-progress">';
}

if($name != true) {
    echo '<img src="../images/progress1.png" class="img-max-progress">';
}
```

You maybe want to change the == true to what @vlzvl says (check if a variable is empty or not)

Comment: I tried your method still no luck, so I tried to check if the variables is empty or not like this:

`elseif((!empty($name)) && (!empty($bio)) && (!empty($address)) && (!empty($phone)) && (!empty($ec)) && (!empty($ecp)) && (!empty($bs))) {
    echo '<img src="../images/progress8.png" class="img-max-progress">';
}`

No luck there either.

Comment: @echo then have your tried to echo those variables to check what they return I you might have tested it but it is all i can think of right now